# How do I overwrite a DOCX XML file with C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, docx

I'm stuck. The goal is to change reviewer names in MS Word track changes using a  C# tool, only if the corresponding date attribute is after a given date. The variable string `docPath` is passed to the method `changeRevAuthor`. `docPath` represents the opened DOCX file. The file MUST be opened when it is passed because the tool also upsaves all DOC files to DOCX before running the method.

The author names ARE changed and the date is confirmed correctly in the XML file. We tested this by saving the XML to a static path. However, what I need to do is actually overwrite the existing XML file, instead of pulling it out and saving it somewhere else. Here is the existing method:

```
    private void changeRevAuthor(string docPath)
    {
        using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.Open(docPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {  
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End); 
            XNamespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
            WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, false);
            XDocument mainDocumentXDoc = document.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();          
            var nodes = mainDocumentXDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attributes(w + "author").Count() > 0);
            var currentdate = "2016-06-21";

            foreach (XElement node in nodes)
            {
                var date = node.Attribute(w + "date").ToString().Substring(8, 10);
                if (DateTime.Parse(date) < DateTime.Parse(currentdate))
                {
                    node.SetAttributeValue(w + "author", "LUZ");
                    Debug.WriteLine(date);
                }                   
            }
            mainDocumentXDoc.Save(document.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create));

        }
    }
```

From research, I believe the final line should do the trick: `mainDocumentXDoc.Save(document.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create));`

However, this returns the following error:

> 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   System.IO.Packaging.dll Additional information: Cannot get stream with
>   FileMode.Create, FileMode.CreateNew, FileMode.Truncate,
>   FileMode.Append when access is FileAccess.Read.'

When I change it to `FileAccess.Write` or `FileAccess.ReadWrite`, I receive the following error:

> 'Additional information: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users....\Desktop\C# Test\Results\newtest.docx' because it is
>   being used by another process.'

Where do I go from here?

Thanks
Luke

Comment: You need to pass `true` to the `WordprocessingDocument.Open` method.

Comment: Tried your suggestion petelids. Error received now: 'Update mode requires a stream with read, write, and seek capabilities.'

Answer (score 0):

This solves your issue:

```
void changeRevAuthor (string docPath)
{
  XNamespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
  WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docPath, true);
  XDocument mainDocumentXDoc = document.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();

  var nodes = mainDocumentXDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attributes(w + "author").Count() > 0);

  foreach (XElement node in nodes)
  {
    // ...
    node.SetAttributeValue(w + "author", "LUZ");        
  }
  mainDocumentXDoc.Save(document.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create));
}
```

but is **incomplete**.

You should also modify *word\comments* and *docProps\core* package parts, not only *word\document*.

Comment: Thank you Andrei. I believe this is very close. I still receive the following error however with your proposed solution: 'Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users....\Desktop\C# Test\Results\newtest.docx' because it is being used by another process.'    This issue is, I believe, that the file is already open when it is passed to this method. This is why we created the stream in the first place. Do you see a way that the stream can be incorporated into your solution?

Comment: You can use process explorer to check open handles for that file. Guard against that file being opened prior to modifying it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the file needs to be open when it is passed to this method. This is because the same tool can do a variety of other tasks on Word files. Because of this, we felt that we had to use a fileStream so that we could edit the OpenXml even though the file is already open.

Comment: Hi Andrei. We have managed to get everything working in the tool now, except updating the reviewer names in the headers and footers. I will submit the full code that we got to work, but could you possibly point us in the right direction for updating these author names in headers and footers?